# Multiple conditions in HAVING clause with NHibernate Criteria?

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, having-clause

I'm trying to use NHibernate's Criteria API to write the equivalent of this:

```
select foo_id from foo_history
group by foo_id
having sum(bar_in) > 0 or sum(baz_in) > 0;
```

with this mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="MVC"
                   namespace="MVC.Model.Things">
  <class name="MVC.Model.Things.FooHistory, MVC"
         table="foo_history">
    <id name="ID" column="foo_hist_id" type="guid"
        unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="BarIn" column="bar_in" type="decimal"
              precision="19" scale="4" not-null="true" />
    <property name="BazIn" column="baz_in" type="decimal"
              precision="19" scale="4" not-null="false" />

    <!-- Foreign Keys -->
    <many-to-one name="Foo" column="foo_id"
                 class="MVC.Model.Things.Foo, MVC.Model.Things"
                 not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this Criteria code (Detached because it will be a subquery):

```
var results = DetachedCriteria.For<FooHistory>("fh")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Id()))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("fh.BarIn"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("fh.BazIn")))
    .Add(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BarIn"), 0) ||
        Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BazIn"), 0))
    .GetExecutableCriteria(session).List();
```

The problem is that adding a conditional restriction after the `SetProjection()` results in NHibernate generating invalid MySQL:

```
SELECT this_.foo_hist_id as y0_,
       sum(this_.bar_in) as y1_,
       sum(this_.baz_in) as y2_
FROM foo_history this_
WHERE (sum(this_.bar_in) > ?p0
       or sum(this_.baz_in) > ?p1)
GROUP BY this_.foo_hist_id
```

...using a WHERE instead of a HAVING. Using a single restriction works fine and everything is correct. I assume that since HN-1280 ("Adds HAVING support to CreateCriteria queries, Fixes parameter order bugs") this is possible but I'm not using the correct "OR" language (e.g., `Restrictions.Disjunction()` just always creates WHERE).

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried: Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BarIn"), 0),
        Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BazIn"), 0))

Comment: @bonifaz: The OR operator is overloaded to provide an `OrExpression`: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/AbstractCriterion.cs#L56-59 ; so it is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with this problem, however i don't think my workaround was good cause it doesn't work for example when you need  ToRowCountQuery() for pagination. But anyway... You can use this class instead of built-in OrExpression

```
class OrHaving : OrExpression
    {
        public OrHaving(ICriterion lhs, ICriterion rhs) : base(lhs, rhs)
        {
        }

        public override IProjection[] GetProjections()
        {
            return LeftHandSide.GetProjections().Concat(RightHandSide.GetProjections()).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

like

```
.Add(new OrHaving (Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BarIn"), 0) ,
                   Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Sum("fh.BazIn"), 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I am very grateful for your answer. From all the different answers and approached I tried, this is the only one that worked for me. (I also inherited the AndExpression, it works like a charm)